# Number of Opportunity Contact Roles

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

Is that possible to create a field in Opportunity with number of Opportunity Contact Roles using trigger or declarative tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can not write trigger or create processes on OpportunityContactRoles, their is no direct way of doing it.

Best way is you write a batch process which runs every day or every hour which will count all opportunityContactroles for given opportunity and update it on respective field of opportunity.

There is [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrdvAAC) which is in Product Team review stage for the same.

Comment: no the best solution to be honest :)

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich Yep, Not provides real time track of the data, but in given circumstances what else can we do. I am all ears for any out of the box solution here.

Comment: does inserting of opportunity contact role fire some background opportunity update? If yes we can do a trigger.

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich No, not in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce Spring '20 Release Opportunity Contact Roles can be used in 
Process Builder, Flow Builder, and workflow rules.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_contacts_automate_oppty_contact_roles.htm